# How did this character appear on the sofa?

Tags: bill-and-ted

In *Bill & Ted Face the Music* (2020), at couples therapy, Joanna and Elizabeth saw their older selves arrive in the present timeline through the phone booth. We see this ancient person sitting on sofa:

[image: The man sat on the sofa as viewed over the shoulder of a woman]

How did this character appear on the sofa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen multiple times in the movie - the universe is broken from Bill and Ted not having succeeded in creating a utopian civilization.  This results in random people throughout history being in the wrong place and time.  Specifically on the couch is George Washington.

This same phenomenon can be seen in the movie Frankenstein Unbound and is similar to Doctor Who The Wedding of River Song.

Speculation: I personally like to think the ending of Bill and Ted 2 was the proper timeline.  Why time went off track is unanswered.

Comment: It's because the main clock (the clock in San Dimas) is always ticking.

Answer (score 2):

At that point in the script, due to the

> '*unravelling of history*'

historical figures like George Washington were randomly dropping through holes in the timeline, something that the [original script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/bill-and-ted-face-the-music-2020.pdf) refers to as "*anachronistic madness*".

This unravelling (due to the failure of Bill and Ted to perform the song that unites everyone in the universe) is the primary reason that the Great Leader decides that she needs to

> kill Bill and Ted.

[image]

[image]